# IOS UITextField custom keyboard will not be dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

I just create a custom keyboard, If I only pop the keyboard once and enter characters in the input box, the keyboard will be dealloc. If I pop up the keyboard twice and enter characters in the input box, the custom keyboard views will not be dealloc. Then I use the Leaks in Xcode, but no memory leak shown on the simulator, when I use a real device to test, some memory leak shown.

I upload my code on github, can anyone help me ?

Swift: https://github.com/arrosev/CCCustomKeyboard

Objc: https://github.com/arrosev/CCCustomKeyboardObjc

VideoPresentation: https://github.com/arrosev/CustomKeyboardDemoVideo

I remember that apple in IOS11 have a problem about UITextField, 
this url:[Retain Cycle (Strong reference) fix for custom uitextfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088704/retain-cycle-strong-reference-fix-for-custom-uitextfield)

I just find if I add this code, the problem will be solved:

```
extension UITextField {

override open func removeFromSuperview() {
    let version : String = UIDevice.current.systemVersion;
    if (version as NSString).doubleValue >= 11.0 {
        let view : UIView? = self.value(forKey: "inputView") as? UIView
        if let temp = view {
            temp.removeFromSuperview()
            self.setValue(nil, forKey: "inputView")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get any issue when I tried ti reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have added some demo videos, the problem is that the number of times the keyboard is displayed will cause different results